# Multiple socket connections in REXX

Tags: sockets, tcp, zos, rexx

Help me with my questions.
I have an client code

```
PARSE ARG NSTR
SERVER = ipaddress                                                  
SERVER_INFO = 'AF_INET 7500 ' !! SERVER                                  
STR = SOCKET('INITIALIZE',TIME('S'))                                     
PARSE VAR STR SOCKRC SUBTASKID MAXDES TCPIPUSER                          
STR = SOCKET('SOCKET', 'AF_INET', 'STREAM', 'TCP')                       
PARSE VAR STR SOCKRC SOCKID                                              
STR = SOCKET('SETSOCKOPT', SOCKID, 'SOL_SOCKET', 'SO_REUSEADDR', 'ON')   
STR = SOCKET('CONNECT', SOCKID, SERVER_INFO)                             
STR = SOCKET('SEND', SOCKID, NSTR)                                       
STR = SOCKET('CLOSE', SOCKID)                                            
STR = SOCKET('TERMINATE', SUBTASKID)                                     
EXIT
```

And i have several scripts in Rexx that give some strings to client (nstr).
One script always run as first, and another as second. Scripts are running fast with minimal delay. 
But when i am receiving these strings on server side i see they are sometimes in a reverse sequence. 
Why is that happening? Should I use an socketid in existing socketset instead of initilize new set ?

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a separate socket (*aka* a separate TCP stream) for every string you send.  TCP doesn't make any promises about how data sent on one stream relates to data sent on another stream.  It only promises that all data sent on a single stream arrives in order and intact.